# Probability problem

Tags: probability

Let's suppose that we're randomly choosing two distinct integers $x, y\in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$. If $xy\in \mathbb{Z}$ is an even integer, then what's the probability that $x+y\in \mathbb{Z}$ will be even as well?

We know that $xy\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x+y\in \mathbb{Z}$ are both even if and only if $x, y\in \mathbb{Z}$ are both even numbers, which happens with the probability $\frac{\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{7}{2}} = \frac{1}{7}$.

Comment: Can one pick $x=y=2$, for instance? Do we pick with or without replacement?

Comment: You counted same probability twice, you included the case of both even numbers in first and second calculation. Notice that the case 'both are even' means that sum and product are even. So $\frac{1}{7}$ should be the answer. I assumed that we can't choose the same number twice.

Comment: @AlvinL $x\neq y$, so no.

Comment: Also, is the question 'what's the probability that $xy$ and $x+y$ are even' or is it 'given that $xy$ is even, what's the probability that $x+y$ is even'? My answer is to the first question.

Comment: @mowzorn Oh, it is actually the latter.

Comment: Then it's a question about conditional probability. Try to use the formula $\mathbb{P}(A|B)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Denote the events $A = $ '$xy$ is even' and $B = $ '$x+y$ is even'. We are interested in $P(B\mid A)$. It holds that $P(B\mid A)P(A) = P(A\cap B)$.

Compute. The product is odd if and only if both terms are odd. There are four odd figures in a pool of $7$ so $P(A^c) = \binom{4}{2} /\binom{7}{2}$.

If $xy$ is even, then at least one term must be even. Thus, if also $x+y$ is even, it follows that both $x$ and $y$ are even. So $P(A\cap B) = \binom{3}{2} / \binom{7}{2}$.